# Way to know when an ObjectUrl has been downloaded (to revoke it...)

Tags: javascript, revokeobjecturl

I would like to delete my Blobs once they are download by the user:

```js
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);           
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = 'myFile' + fileExtension;
a.href = url;
a.click();//download launched

/** Here i want to revoke the ObjectURL and delete my Blob, but i dunno when? **/
```

Can i do this without using a dummy timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply revoke the URL when the blob has been accessed, use a `click` event handler.

```
a.onclick = function () {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

To check that the blob has actually been *downloaded*, you will need to download it via XHR where you can monitor its download progress using `progress` and `load` events. As far as I know you cannot monitor download progress in JavaScript for something initiated outside of XHR.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress